# What whould Be The Best Method To Count From Child To Last Parent Entries In Database

Tags: mysql, database

I need to count all posts posted by users in one or more child categories while retrieving parent category.

Like I have a table 'categories',

```
ID    Parent_ID
1     0
2     1
3     1
4     2
```

Other table 'posts'

```
P_ID  P_CONTENT  CAT_ID
1     blah blah  2
2     blah blah  4
```

Users submit there post under any child category which must should have a parent. 
Child category could maybe 4 or 2 or any.

And now my problem is to count all posts to there end parent category.

Like counting all post of category 4 and 2 into parent category while retrieving parent category.

Frankly speaking, I didn't tried anything as my mind is not working in this scenario and i am unable to make any logic and i am not so experts in queries. Hope you guys understand. Thanks!

Comment: mysql sucks at this - you could try looking [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20110606032941/http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html), or just go and do it at your application level, or come up with a stored procedure to do it for you

Comment: Actually this is web based application. And i am working in PHP, So i must have to use mysql :(

Comment: well, you could do it in php, but ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your table structure above, the only way to get the n-most parent id is to look through your parents until there are no more. You can't do this with a single query in MySQL. If you have to do it in the database, then you need to use a stored to procedure to keep fetching the parent_id while one exists.

This stored procedure will calculate the top most parent for a given category.

```
drop function getlastancestor;
delimiter $$
create function getlastancestor(cat_id int) returns int
deterministic
begin
  declare anc int; -- variable to hold our ancestor
  declare cur int; -- current ancestor we are looking at
  set anc = cat_id; -- initialise it to the category_id we are checking
  set cur = cat_id; -- same again
  while cur > 0 do  -- exit our loop when we find a parent_id = 0
    select ifnull(parent_id, 0) into cur
      from
        (select parent_id
          from categories
          where id = cur) q;    -- find the parent_id of our current ancestor
    if cur > 0 then
      set anc = cur;            -- if it has one, then we update our ancestor to its value
    end if;
  end while;
  return anc;     -- return the top most ancestor
end $$
delimiter ;
```

and you would use it something like this:

```
select getlastancestor(cat_id) parent, count(*) cnt
  from posts
  group by getlastancestor(cat_id);
```

[demo fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07a43/1) using some made up data

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if you explain a little i would be really thankful to you. As did not ever work with functions. Thanks

Comment: i've updated with a slightly extended description, as well as a demo. If it's not working for you then your table names and field names are different to whats in your question.