# While Loop in MySQL Script that Contains a Cascading Update

Tags: mysql, loops, while-loop

so I have this table (shortened for simplicity) and I have a crafted a while loop, but know I am doing something wrong or just dont understand while loops in MySQL

the sample table is

```
sample_table
---------------------------------
entity_id     parent_id     int_1
---------------------------------
1             0             5
7             1             0
10            1             3
11            10            2
12            11            0
13            11            0
```

int_1 is the number of child objects and the entities are that of a tree structure ie

```
1---7
|
10--11---12
|
13
```

I want to update the number of child objects after entering another branch or child, ie entity_id 14  this has already been set up through a somewhat easy process through a SQL script, but after addition I end up with this table

```
entity_id     parent_id     int_1
---------------------------------
1             0             5
7             1             0
10            1             3
11            10            2
12            11            0
13            11            0
14            13            0
```

I thought I could just add this after my script to update, mind you @parent_entity has already been defined in the script beforehand

```
while @parent_entity > 0 do
    update sampe_table set int_1=int_1+1 where entity_id = @parent_entity;
    set @parent_entity = (select parent_id from sample_table where entity_id = @parent_entity);
end while
```

this obviously didnt work or i wouldnt be asking

must i put this into a procedure?  is it because @parent_entity is already predefined?

the resulting table I am looking for is

```
entity_id     parent_id     int_1
---------------------------------
1             0             6
7             1             0
10            1             4
11            10            3
12            11            0
13            11            1
14            13            0
```

anything helpful is much appreciated

Comment: it needs to go in a procedure

Comment: I'd be tempted to look at nested sets instead

Comment: @pala_  if it needs to go in a procedure then why doesnt it say so in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/while.html
sure it has it in one in an example but it never says in the documentation it must go in a procedure

Comment: if you back up to its grandparent document item, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html, it says exactly that

Comment: ok fine i did read that as you responded, but let me ask you this, if that is the case and i save this as a procedure then do i have to declare @parent_entity in the procedure since it is created in the script that would call the procedure?
but still i do think its a little vague, it never explicitly states that while loops are only in procedures it says they CAN contain... but we are splitting hairs

Comment: you may find this question somewhat useful - it's fairly similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29898614/what-whould-be-the-best-method-to-count-from-child-to-last-parent-entries-in-dat/29900153#29900153

Comment: well i think i know what i have to do, but my previous question remains is the variable fine without declaration in the procedure, because if i call it and declare it with it already holding an integer wont it null the variable?

Answer (score 0):

ok the loop is right, but i do need to make the procedure as stated so this worked for me

```
delimiter $$
create procedure updatechildcount()
begin
    while @parent_entity > 0 do
        update sampe_table set int_1=int_1+1 where entity_id = @parent_entity;
        set @parent_entity = (select parent_id from sample_table where entity_id = @parent_entity);
    end while;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

yes it was that simple so thanks pala_

and in order to run it is

call updatechildcount()